# issues with QFileDialog

Tags: python, pyqt5

I use pyqt5 lib in python to construct my GUI , but I need to make QFileDialog to get file name from user , I already constructed it but it cause error when user enters file name only without extension , I want to get only file name from user and get extension automatically

note:this error happens only on windows OS , I run the same script on Linux OS and no errors raised

```
def browse(self):
    #directory='.' to set default directory of any system , filter to get file types 
    save_place=QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,caption='save as',directory='.',filter='All Files(*.*)')
    #slicing to get path only
    name=str(save_place) #because it's tuble by defult
    path=(name[2:].split(',')[0].replace("'",""))
    self.lineEdit_2.setText(path) #getting path to line edit box
```

this error message i get

[image]

Comment: show code as text. in SO we hate that it shows the code as an image. :D

Comment: ok , one moment please

Comment: Read [ask]..... :D

Comment: I just added it as text

Comment: You could show the error message.

Comment: i add a screenshot of error

Comment: it seems that in windows you can not create a file without extension.

Comment: Change `save_place=` to `path, _=`

Comment: Use: `def browse(self):
    path, _ =QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,caption='save as',directory='.',filter='All Files(*.*)')
    self.lineEdit_2.setText(path)`

Comment: nothing happen ....

Comment: What does it mean that nothing happens?, It is explicit, we are not in your machine, we do not know what mistakes you have.

Comment: I mean I got the same error when I tried your code

Comment: Have you tried creating a file without extensions directly in windows? That error message is Windows-specific, it is not due to PyQt.

Comment: ok , but how could I overcome this issue and getting file extension automatically !!! , like other programs such as IDM

Comment: @abdelrahman. Try with `filter='Text Files(*.txt)'`. Or set a filter with whatever extension you want to use.

Comment: @ekhumoro my friend it's supposed to be a download app project , no control to what is possible to be downloaded from users

Comment: @abdelrahman. Can you please just try it and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: i tried it recently , it works but problem not solved , I need to get extension of any file from any download link or overcome this simply

Comment: @abdelrahman. Okay, so now try: `filter='All Files (*.*);;Text Files (*.txt)'`.

Comment: same error message above

Comment: @abdelrahman. In the file-dialog, try putting the file-name in quotes - i.e. `"test"`, instead of `test`.

Comment: it performs the download but file downloaded have no extension and unknown for windows !

Comment: @abdelrahman. But you **asked** for it to have no extension. Why are you trying to save it with no extension?

Comment: I want to save it with its extention, But not got by user, I want to make user enter only file name

Comment: @abdelrahman. In that case, you need to [determine the mimetype](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html#module-mimetypes) of the dowloaded file, and then provide an appropriate filter for it (as described above).

Comment: Ok I will try this solution thank you